# Why do I still see the Windows partition from my Ubuntu installation?

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, installation, partitioning

Did I install Ubuntu correctly? Can I just copy and move stuff from and to that partition when I'm working in Ubuntu? I'm pretty sure I installed Ubuntu into a second partition, but for some reason I can also see the Windows files.

edit: so strange, I only have a single 1TB harddrive. The 452gb filesystem is the Windows partition. The "Filesystem" seems to be from Ubuntu, but the rest is not clear. It looks as if the Ubuntu installation didn't even remove any files in the partition I installed it into. (I installed it into a 300gb partition, at least that's what I selected)

In addition, I don't understand why the "system reserved" keeps showing up. There are these folders inside: "Boot" "System Volume Information" "bootmgr" "BOOTSECT.BAK"

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this will help.
NTFS (New Technology File System) is a file system developed by Microsoft and used by Windows computers (Windows 2000 and later). Until 2007, linux was not able to write to this type of filesystem, it could only read from it. The stable ntfs-3g driver now allows linux systems to read and write NTFS formatted partitions.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

Comment: The system reserved is a partition which contains either restore information and is put in place by computer manufacturer or is a partition made by Windows 7 during installation. It is normally hidden in windows. I'd say that it's normal behavior for it to be detected by GNU/Linux and mounted using ntfs-3g.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu will let you mount the Windows partition and read and write files to it.  Do you see something like "Windows_OS" under your "Places" menu?

Comment: No, I see a whole lot of different folders. Even my usb harddrive still shows up, even though I removed it long ago. (I even clicked on "unmount" several times) I'll add a screenshot to the original post.

Comment: on second thought, it's probably not my usb harddrive, I'm just confused because there are so many

Comment: I'm getting a 404 on that screenshot.

Comment: I uploaded it from my computer now, so it should be hosted at Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Blub Still not showing up here.